# Original OS install date is June but software install date in March, How's this possible?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, oem

I checked someone's brand new laptop which had an OS install date of June, while some software shows the installation date as March. How's this possible?

Folders inside `C:/users/<username>` also show the install date as March.

Comment: OS was refreshed?

Comment: Could have been a Windows 10 feature update.

Comment: A Windows 10 Repair Install will do this as well.

Comment: @DavidPostill what you mean by refresh?

Comment: This is very common. I see files in installs with dates well before the system was installed. Years, even. It matters what date you are looking at, and knowing what they're actually telling you jf you.

Answer (score 2):

OEMs generally use an image of the OS, and copy said image to the new computer before selling it. That image may have been made in March.

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade windows 10 to a different build, I.e. 2004, then the original installation date which wis found in registry or wmi win32_operatingsystem provider is overwritten to the upgrade date in UNIX date-time format. So you never get the actual installation date, each build upgrade is regarded as new fresh windows installation.